# Why the use of 'new Date()' & how to get 0 in front of numbers smaller then 10 ? - Digital Clock Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

as I go ahead with my learning JS journey I try to build small projects.

Today I've built a digital clock (a little by myself and a [bigger] little by following a tutorial).

There are 2 small things that I don't understand and that they don't explain in the tutorial. By the way, if anyone interested [Here the tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CWOnjWTfPW4).

**HERE THE JS CODE**

```
setInterval(function() {
  let hours = document.querySelector('.hours')
  let minutes = document.querySelector('.minutes')
  let seconds = document.querySelector('.seconds')

  let h = new Date().getHours();
  let m =  new Date().getMinutes();
  let s = new Date().getSeconds();

  hours.innerHTML = hours.innerHTML = h<10?'0'+h:h;
  minutes.innerHTML = m<10?'0'+m:m;
  seconds.innerHTML =  s<10?'0'+s:s;

  
}, 1000);
```

**Small thing n°1:**

Why the use of `new Date()`? I belive `new` keyword has something to do with objects, but I'm not sure. I just started giving a glance into objects. I tried `hours.innerHTML = getHours()` which in my eyes was ok, but of course it didn't work. How come?

**Small thing n°2:**

By following the tutorial, if hours, minutes and seconds were below 10, they would've appear like 7, 2, 4, 9 etc, instead of 07, 02, 04, 09 etc.

I tried a mix of logic and knowledge (spoiler allert = it didn't work) and said

```
if(m < 10) {
 '0' + s
}
```

I also tried:

```
if(m < 10) {
 s= '0' + s
 return s
}
```

which maybe it's wrong, but sorry I'm learning...

You guessed it! It didn't work!

I then looked through the comments and a guy posted the code to have the `0` before numbers smaller then `10` but it is a shorthand and I don't quite understand it, especially I don't understand, why there is a `:h`, `:m`, `:s` at the end of every statement?

**HERE THE SNIPPET**

```js
setInterval(function() {
  let hours = document.querySelector('.hours')
  let minutes = document.querySelector('.minutes')
  let seconds = document.querySelector('.seconds')

  let h = new Date().getHours();
  let m =  new Date().getMinutes();
  let s = new Date().getSeconds();

  hours.innerHTML = h<10?'0'+h:h;
  minutes.innerHTML = m<10?'0'+m:m;
  seconds.innerHTML =  s<10?'0'+s:s;

  
}, 1000);
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  background: black;
}

.container {
  width: 90vw;
  margin: auto;
  border: 1px solid rgb(50,50,50);
  margin-top: 50vh;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  padding: .5em;
  font-size: 3em;
  font-family: verdana;
  background: rgb(170,190,170);
  box-shadow: 0 0 10px black inset;
  box-reflect: below 0 linear-gradient(transparent, white);
  -webkit-box-reflect: below 0 linear-gradient(transparent, rgba(255,255,255,.5));
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <title>Digital Clock</title>
</head>
<body>
  
  <div class="container">
    <div class="hours"></div>
    <div class="minutes"></div>
    <div class="seconds"></div>
  </div>

  <script src="main.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `h<10?'0'+h:h` is a ternary operator for if. So you read it: if h is less then 10 then (the part after the question mark) concatenate '0' and h, else (the part after the:) print only h

Comment: @LelioFaieta oh, got it! thanks a lot! So without the shorthand I should've just add the else and return h or m or s

Comment: without the shorthand you should add a full if-else block to have the same result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Small thing n°1:

- Why the use of new Date()?
  The date object has to be created first to get the current date and time.
  The function ( getHours() ) will then get the hours from this created date.

Small thing n°2:

- Why there is a :h, :m, :s at the end of every statement?
  This is the format for how this shorthand is done.

```
STATEMENT ? IF_TRUE : IF_FALSE
```

Explanation: [link](https://codeburst.io/javascript-the-conditional-ternary-operator-explained-cac7218beeff)

In this case `h<10?'0'+h:h` means that if `h < 10` the innerHTML is set to `'0' + h`.
If h >= 10 than innerHTML is h.

```
if(m < 10) {
 s= '0' + s
 return s
}
```

This did not work because of the statement in the if.
The variable is 'm' which is not the comparison in the tutorial it is 's' in this case.

I hope this clarifies it a bit more :)

Answer (score 2):

You got a [conditional (ternary) operator `?:`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator) which has three parts:

```
condition ? valueTrue : valueFalse
```

- *`condition`* which is an expression which has a [truthy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Truthy), like `true`, any string without `''`, any number without `0` or `NaN`, objects, functions or [falsy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Falsy) value, like `undefined`, `null`, `''`, zero.
- *`valueTrue`*, this is an expression which is returned if the condition is *truthy* and
- *`valueFalse`*, this is an expression which is returned if the condition is *falsy*.

And because it may look handy for having an inline condition, it is not advisable to use it if the return value do not matter.

For a shorter approach, you could convert the value to a string and pad at start with necessary zeroes. For using this method more than once, use a function for it.

For getting a `Date` instance, you could take it once and use it for getting all time parts.

```js
function padZero(value) {
    return value.toString().padStart(2, '0');
}

setInterval(function() {
    let hours = document.querySelector('.hours'),
        minutes = document.querySelector('.minutes'),
        seconds = document.querySelector('.seconds'),
        today = new Date();

    hours.innerHTML = padZero(today.getHours());
    minutes.innerHTML = padZero(today.getMinutes());
    seconds.innerHTML = padZero(today.getSeconds());
}, 200);
```

```html
<span class="hours"></span>:<span class="minutes"></span>:<span class="seconds"></span>
```